# Cross section 2D data of symmetric len into Z matrix MATLAB - 3D plot from 2D cross section

Tags: matlab, matrix, 3d, plot, 2d

I have a problem and maybe you will be able to help me. Like in the title i have cross section data of a symmetric lens - coordinates `s=-100:1:100` and height `y` - and I would like to create 3D plot the whole lens `(x,y,z)`. Is there any build in function that helps with that? Thanks for help in advance!

Comment: sorry, I dont get it. you have 2 data: S and Y. how do you want to plot a 3D plot?

Comment: If 'y' is a one dimensional array, Can we assume you want the surface graph of the top half of the symmetric lens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding correctly, you have a 1-D array that you'd effectively like to 'sweep' around a circle to produce a 3-D plot. Here is an example of how to do that

```
% Some dummy data
Npts = 100;
z = sin(linspace(0, pi, Npts));

Nreps = 100; % How many times to repeat around circle
% Create polar meshgrid and convert to Cartesian
[r, theta] = meshgrid( ...
    linspace(-length(z)/2, length(z)/2, Npts), ...
    linspace(0, pi, Nreps));
[X, Y] = pol2cart(theta, r);
% Copy data Nreps times
Z = repmat(z, Nreps, 1);

% Plot!
surf(X, Y, Z)
```

Answer (score 0):

Without more specs (such as if your `y` is a 2D matrix or a 1D array), it's not possible to give you the exact answer. However here is how you draw a surface in Matlab:

```
% create a meshgrid used as the independent variables of your surface
[sx, sy] = meshgrid(-100:100); 
% if you have your own 2D matrix, ignore this line. 
% if you have a formula, replace this line with your own formula
y = cos(sqrt(((sx/100).^2+(sy/100).^2)/2)*(pi/2));
% draw the surface
surf(sx, sy, y);
```

To have the opposite side as well, draw another surf on the same figure:

```
hold on;
surf(sx, sy, -y);
```